# How to create submit button using Struts tag?

Tags: struts2

Can any one tell me how to create submit button in Struts?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `s:submit` tag is all you really need to do.

For example, let's say you have a form that will submit a simple textfield value into a variable in your action called `"name"`:

```jsp
<s:form action="MyAction">
  <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" required="true"/>
  <s:submit value="Click Here to Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: You should click the "answered" link :)